Keycloak: Mapping different client roles to AD-Group-Member?
I have a keycloak setup where I synch AD-Group-Memberships into my Realm.
When I create a role mapping for an AD-Group, that role gets added to the tokens of every client.
role mapping using client role
What I want to do, is select a single client-role and map THAT to the members of the AD-Group. So that the role "Administrators" is only added to the access token of the client "eidpki-dev-1"
Am I using the feature wrong or is this a bug in KC 25?
